# How do I get the fragment identifier (value after hash #) from a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-fragment

Example:

```
www.site.com/index.php#hello
```

Using jQuery, I want to put the value `hello` in a variable:

```
var type = …
```

Comment: I’m uncertain, whether this question should remain being tagged as jQuery and asking about it. Most of the answers apply to JS without jQuery and this seems like a good dupe target.

Answer (score 642, accepted):

No need for jQuery

```
var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

---

Since [`String.prototype.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is deprecated use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead.

```
var type = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```

Comment: Not enough jQuery! (Just kidding: +1.)

Comment: I just learned that a # can be used as 'hash' which works as an identifier / keyword in JavaScript. Awesome

Comment: You can also use `.slice(1)` instead of `.substr(1)` which should offer a modest increase in performance, although it makes no difference in real life.

Comment: OMG, how many times you'd need to check url hash to make ANY noticeable difference? A million? 'Modest increase' is a huge overstatement in this context. :-)

Comment: How about URL's from variables? This answer works only with current `window.location` value.

Comment: @konrad plenty of websites get millions of page loads a day.

Comment: @Kröw yes but we speak of client side code not server side. It doesn't matter unless one browser has to load millions of sites a day which in most cases it doesn't. :-)

Comment: @konrad Yes it does.

Comment: @Kröw can you explain?

Comment: `substr` is deprecated. use `substring` or `slice` instead

Answer (score 37):

You may do it by using following code:

```
var url = "www.site.com/index.php#hello";
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#')+1);
alert(hash);
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/6zVZA/)**

Comment: Note: indexOf is not supported by IE8

Comment: @SchalkKeun luckily, now in '18 it's almost gone. But for those who still have to deal with that legend should be aware of it.

Comment: To be honest, IE8 is so insecure, all the payment gateways basically is going to drop any browser not supporting TLS 1.2 next week (30 June 2018), you will not be able to do payments from them at all. So that makes all these old crappy browsers useless for any ecommerce client.

Answer (score 13):

```
var url ='www.site.com/index.php#hello';
var type = url.split('#');
var hash = '';
if(type.length > 1)
  hash = type[1];
alert(hash);
```

Working demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghk64/1/)

Comment: The `if` statement can be shortened to `var hash = type[1] || "";`.

Answer (score 8):

It's very easy. Try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var hashValue = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');  
  //do something with the value here  
});
```

Comment: var hashValue = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');

Answer (score 8):

Use the following JavaScript to get the value after hash (#) from a URL. You don't need to use jQuery for that.

```
var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
```

I have got this code and tutorial from here - [How to get hash value from URL using JavaScript](http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-guides/get-hash-value-from-url-using-javascript/)

Answer (score 5):

I had the URL from run time, below gave the correct answer:

```
let url = "www.site.com/index.php#hello";
alert(url.split('#')[1]);
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

**Get fragment of current document location**

```js
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

**Get fragment from string**

```js
// absolute
var url = new URL('https://example.com/path/index.html#hash');

console.log(url.hash);

// relative (second param is required, use any valid URL base)
var url2 = new URL('/path/index.html#hash2', 'http://example');

console.log(url2.hash);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on A.K's code, here is a Helper Function. JS Fiddle Here (http://jsfiddle.net/M5vsL/1/) ...

```
// Helper Method Defined Here.
(function (helper, $) {
    // This is now a utility function to "Get the Document Hash"
    helper.getDocumentHash = function (urlString) {
        var hashValue = "";

        if (urlString.indexOf('#') != -1) {
            hashValue = urlString.substring(parseInt(urlString.indexOf('#')) + 1);
        }
        return hashValue;
    };
})(this.helper = this.helper || {}, jQuery);
```