# Request Url # not?

Tags: c#, http, request

how to get variable access_token ?

http://web.com/FBAout.aspx#access_token=AAACsvdmyOAgBAL1dVbN1t1ydGQNG4LvZCGjtJM6oXkO6IUObDdJsZBYqHQbTq401mvzD0cXMdsAOZAPEBnIxYF58zCv8ZBcErcsaWL4QOo6MxnPFZCRPL&expires_in=5103

the problem is that url use # not ?

any body help me?

Comment: I've no idea what you're talking about =(. Could you be more specific?

Comment: You cannot get it on server side

Comment: i want to get value access_token, with Request.QueryString["access_token"]
but the result is blank but if i chage # with [?] i get that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting values after the hash (#) is not possible server side because they're not sent by the browser.

Best chance is retrieve them from javascript and then post that to your server.

Comment: thanks' Matthew, for your quick response.. can you please help me with simple code, how to retrieve them from javascript

Comment: You're looking for a combination of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662693/how-do-i-get-the-value-after-hash-from-a-url-using-jquery with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript, in the parse query string example, you would replace `window.location.search.substring(1);` with `window.location.hash.substr(1);`, or something similar.