# Use URL Parameter to call a line of text using JS?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, url-parameters

I'm hoping to call a line of text by using a simple URL parameter. Say I had an ordered list in javascript and on load of url `example.com/?i=14` would get the 14th line in my list and place it where desired.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried making a function that does what you describe and calling that when you click a button?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "call a line of text," but maybe you could do this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var queryPos = url.indexOf('i=');
var param = url.substr(queryPos + 'i='.length);
```

Now param will contain the value of the parameter and you could use it to fetch whatever.

But since you're trying to access a value from a URL with JavaScript, it might be better to make use of # as explained here: [How do I get the value after hash (#) from a URL using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662693/how-do-i-get-the-value-after-hash-from-a-url-using-jquery) (there are non-jquery answers as well)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you need.
To place an array element where you need it on document load

```
<div id="placeHere"></div>
```

In JS

```
document.body.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('placeHere').innerHTML = array[14];
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#placeHere').html(array[14]);
})
```