# leaflet geosearch - search for location from outside of leaflet map container

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I would like to be able to have my map centered at a pre-entered location. For example:

Page 1: user submits a location and gets redirect to page 2

Page 2: takes input from page 1 and centers map based off of the location

Assuming input from page 1 is saved into variable 'location', I've tried:

```
<script src="/static/js/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/l.control.geosearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/l.geosearch.provider.google.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var googleGeocodeProvider = new L.GeoSearch.Provider.Google();
    var map = L.map('map', {center: [30.27, -97.75], zoom: 10, maxZoom: 18, minZoom: 3});
    L.tileLayer(''http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
       attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'}).addTo(map);
    var geosearch = new L.Control.GeoSearch({
        provider: googleGeocodeProvider
    }).addTo(map);
    googleGeocodeProvider.GetLocations(location, function (data) {
        console.log(data);  # according to docs (https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch), data should have the x,y info I'm looking for
    });
```

The above code returns the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geocode' of      undefinedL.GeoSearch.Provider.Google.L.Class.extend.GetLocations @  l.geosearch.provider.google.js:39(anonymous function) @ (index):357
```

Edit:

Sorry Ghybs, I should have been more clear about the issue that I had.  I am using django to service web requests and I'm able to pass variables between pages easily.  The issue was that I was not able to call geosearch outside of the leaflet map with a given query and have it return the coordinates I need to re-center the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error that I got by customizing the l.geosearch.provider.google.js script, replace:

```
var geocoder = L.GeoSearch.Provider.Google.Geocoder;
```

with:

```
var geocoder;
if (L.GeoSearch.Provider.Google.Geocoder)
    geocoder = L.GeoSearch.Provider.Google.Geocoder;
else
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

If someone has a better solution, please let me know! (such as somehow calling the geosearch function within the map object)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot pass the value of JavaScript variables from one page to another as simply. You need to use a "persistent" storage, that the next page can read and take action on (like setting the view to a previously user-supplied position and zoom, as you require).

2 simple ways of doing so are:

- With the browser location bar, usually using the hash/fragment part. See plugin [Leaflet.RestoreView](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.RestoreView).
- With the browser HTML5 localStotarge. See plugin [Leaflet-hash](https://github.com/mlevans/leaflet-hash).

You can also try [other Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#bookmarked-panzoom).

You could also try to implement your own version of method 1, so that you pass the "location" directly as a string that your geocode provider object can manage, rather than coordinates (as is done with the 2nd plugin for example). It could be written either in the [hash or the query part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax). There are numerous small JavaScript libraries that could help you with that.

The nice advantage of method 1 is that you can actually use the link as a *permalink* to your 2nd page that points directly to the correct location!

---

EDIT:

For retrieving the hash part of the URL in your location bar (method 1), see [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662693/how-do-i-get-the-value-after-hash-from-a-url-using-jquery).

Since you tagged jQuery, you could use it to [store / retrieve data in localStorage](http://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/data-storage/) (method 2).