# How to get #!hashbang value in a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

For example, I have this URL:

```
http://www.shafadoc.ir/#!mykey=ali
```

how can get the value of mykey?

Comment: `document.location.hash` client side, it is not submitted server side. Also, you'll have to parse it yourself.

Comment: See this post if it's useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662693/how-do-i-get-the-value-after-hash-from-a-url-using-jquery

Comment: `[http://www.shafadoc.ir/#!mykey=ali][1]`? Doesn't look like anything valid... It's like the second key of an array with one key containing an unquoted string...

Comment: yes, i edit that.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari, # with #! not different?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one parameter you can do that:

```
var param = location.search.split('mykey=')[1]
```

EDIT:

This is probably better:

```
var param = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```