# I need to get values from a url after (#) with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have this url:

```
http://test.words.aspx#word_id=1034374#lang_code=en
```

I need to get the values of word_id and Language code and assign them to variables.

```
var word_id = 1034374;
var lang_kod = en;
```

Comment: Is it possible you can amend that URL structure? There should really only be one fragment in the URL.

Comment: hint `document.location`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value after hash (#) from a URL using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662693/how-do-i-get-the-value-after-hash-from-a-url-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
var link = window.location;

var data = link.split("#");

var word_id = data[1].split("=")[1];
var lang_code = data[2].split("=")[1];
```

With `window.location` you get the url that you currently are (an alternative is `document.location`.

Then you split it by the hash symbol (`link.split("#")`) and the result is stored as an array of strings (`data`) which now contains `http://test.words.aspx` at index 0, `word_id=1034374` at index 1 and `lang_code=en` at index 2;

What you have to do now is split the string at index 1 by the equals symbol (`data[1].split("=")`). This also is an array of string which has the `word_id` at index 0 and `1034374` at index 1 which is what you need (`data[1].split("=")[1]`).

Following the same logic you also get the `lang_code` variable.

Test it here:

```js
var link = "http://test.words.aspx#word_id=1034374#lang_code=en"

var data = link.split("#");

var word_id = data[1].split("=")[1];
var lang_code = data[2].split("=")[1];

console.log("Word ID = " + word_id);
console.log("Lang Code = " + lang_code);
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: That's simple and effective.
Thanks mate. :)

Comment: You are welcome. You can also upvote my answer ;) Since you are new here check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I'm trying but it gives me this message
Votes casts with those less than 15 reputation are recorded.!

Comment: Oh you must have 15 reputation or more to upvote. Then you could accept my answer (the tick button). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) how

Answer (score 0):

You should really only have one URL fragment. But in your case you could do the following to achieve this.

```
var url = "http://test.words.aspx#word_id=1034374#lang_code=en"; // or use window.location;
var url_splitted = url.split('#');

alert((url_splitted[1]).split('=')[1]); // showing you the values
alert((url_splitted[2]).split('=')[1]); // showing you the values

var work_id = (url_splitted[1]).split('=')[1];
var lang_code = (url_splitted[2]).split('=')[1];
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o0nwyvfz/

**Note:**

If you are about to use multiple URL fragments, I'd suggest you to use URL parameters e.g.: **http://test.words.aspx?word_id=1034374&lang_code=en**

Which you could retrieve by:

A solution provided by: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

And this is how you can use this function assuming the URL is,
http://test.words.aspx?word_id=1034374&lang_code=en

```
var tech = getUrlParameter('word_id');
var blog = getUrlParameter('lang_code');
```